# Call recorder not working on 7.1.1. Others side person voice is not recording

Tags: android, android-ndk, call-recording

I have a call recording app. I am using CallRecordingservice to record voice through  `AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION`
in Android **8 (Oreo) , 6** and below working with some device but not in **Android 7**

I just found that something related to 7 that Android 7 has some  security protocols and we have to overrite `libmedia.so` using NDK.

Note : I have tested 6.0 Devices and below versions also. For Nougat(7) device i have tested with **Motorola G5** and **Motorola G4** .

Same issues found here : [Call Recording Issue 7.1.1](https://github.com/vishal044/Call-Recorder/issues/1)

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific about what these "security protocols" are. In general, using native code does not allow your app to do anything it wouldn't be allowed to do in Java code. The main reasons why someone would use the NDK is to improve performance and/or to use some legacy code that was written in C or C++. Also, there's no guarantee that every Android device will support voice call recording. Some do, and some don't.

Comment: But i show one App called  
Call Recorder - ACR- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.acr   is working with 7.1.1 . I dont know which solution can be worked .

Comment: If their is no support of call recording for Motorola G 
 seriers then How it works in this App. I tested with M0to G5 and Moto g4. both working

Comment: I found blackbox and boldbeast both work on moto G5

Comment: @HarshBhavsar do you find any solution?