# Record calls in Oreo+

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to capture call recordings of both caller and called persons so far it can only capture one side in devices above android 7.0.0 .Altough this question has been asked many times such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231232/android-call-recording-incoming-voice-not-getting-recorded), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android) , and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843495/call-recorder-not-working-on-7-1-1-others-side-person-voice-is-not-recording) .I did not find any working code and i am getting the impression it's impossible. I keep asking myself a simple question. Why at least 3 apps [app1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smsrobot.callu) ,[app2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cherinbo.callrecorder),[app3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder)in google play has this functionality working great in android 7.0.0 and above. And how do they make it work?

Comment: "And how do they make it work?" -> most likely they use a (very) low targetSdk, so either they don't have to ask permissions explicitly, or they use old code which would allow that. Very soon such apps won't be able to update to new versions until they will increase the (low) targetSdk, but when they'll do so they'll loose their functionalities. Android is becoming more and more strict, accept it and embrace it

Comment: You can't do it anymore by targeting latest SDK. See the new restrictions https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/

Comment: But i found apps that record calls for android 8 and 8.1.1 flawlessly (api  24+). How do you explain that?

Comment: please link the apps so they can be analyzed. alternatively do it yourself using apktool

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan I would really appreciate if you could help me analyze those apps. I added links. thanks in advance!

Comment: I spent few months to disassemble those Apps where this feature is working and THERE IS a solution (I never tried on Android Pie 9 yet) but it uses a bug/forgotten_opened_hole in Android, so I think it will be fixed/changed in future resulting in a not-more-working method. Obliviously I prefer to keep my knowledge as PRIVATE, but I don't understand why Android never supported developers on voicecall recording making the things easier for us........